# Jquery mobile listview - check initialization is complete

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I've coded my way into a corner.

I need to call `listview("refresh")` on a list, however it may not have been initialized at the point I am calling the refresh method.

Is there a way to check if the component has initialized or not?

This is the error I get:

> cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization

Comment: Some example code would be nice, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: That's the problem with modular development Phill, It's very difficult to produce the same scenario in jsfiddle. I'm calling a method on a loaded module not knowing whether a listview has been initialized or not. This would be dependent on the speed of the user connection. I've solved it for the time being by using a flag. I just thought there might be a way to call the listview component and check its status.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When a `listview` widget is initialized, it's given the `ui-listview` class, so we can test for this class to see if it has been initialized:

```
//select the listview
var $myUL = $('#my-ul-element');

//add a list-item to the listview
$myUL.append('<li>I\'m New!</li>');

//check if the listview has the ui-listview class
if ($myUL.hasClass('ui-listview')) {

    //this listview has already been initialized, so refresh it
    $myUL.listview('refresh');
} else {

    //this listview has not yet been initialized, so it gets initialized
    $myUL.listview();//or you can use .trigger('create');
}
```

This should help alleviate the error you're getting.

Also, the `.hasClass('[class]')` function returns `true`/`false` if the element has the `[class]`: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass

Comment: Bingo. Good answer - thanks, Just hope they don't change the class name. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$list.listview();
$list.listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution to this message was to add `data-role="listview"` to my `ul` element. I could then use the method `.listview('refresh')` in my event handlers.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply create a global variable

var is_mobile_init = false;

at the top of your scripts. then set it to true after you include jquery mobile.

then before refreshing write,

```
if (is_mobile_init)
    $myUL.listview('refresh');
```

this way, you don't need to keep track of all the various classes and it is intuitive