# jquery mobile listview refresh same list lose style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to update the content of a ul list passing from a list to another one.
The 1st list is generated from a search form wich calls a ajax request. It's styled correctly.
For the second list i use empty() on the list and get the parameter to search (via ajax) from the 1st list as a link attribute

```
$('.myLink').live("vclick", function() {
    var param= $(this).attr('id');
    ...
```

The feature is working. But the 2nd list doesn't have the jquery mobile style.

On pageshow I'm refreshing the list

```
$('#listID').listview('refresh');
```

but pageshow triggers only when I generate the 1st list, not the second one (which is in the same ul as the 1st).

I tried pageinit, pagecreate, pagechange and pageshow but none of them triggers when I update the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed changing the whole project: now I have 2 single pages and 1 multipage. Having the list in a single page solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Refresh the list just after you've updated it's HTML. Something like:

```
$("#listID").append($("<li />").text("Some Text")).listview("refresh");
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R98La/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I get
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
I already tried that one (sadly) :(
I also tried to add
$("#listID").listview();
before adding the li elements and then calling refresh: same error

Comment: @Ciack404 I'm not sure where you're running your code but that error means that the widget has not yet been initialized. You may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493215/jquery-mobile-listview-check-initialization-is-complete/9493671#9493671

Comment: Fixed changing the whole project: now I have 2 single pages and 1 multipage.
Having the list in a single page solved the issue.
Thanks again

Comment: worked for me after I checked if the listview had already been created.  `if($("#listID").hasClass('ui-listview')) { $("#listID").listview('refresh'); }`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#listID').listview('refresh');
$(".ui-page").trigger("create");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The problem is that I'm unable to call those function on the second list since it doesn't trigger any of the event I mention in my question.
And using "create" on vclick doesn't change anything. Still w/o jquery mobile style.

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter by mistake in the prev comment. Now edited

Comment: Fixed changing the whole project: now I have 2 single pages and 1 multipage.
Having the list in a single page solved the issue.
Thanks again