# Error refreshing ListView with jQuery and 'changePage'

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have this error:

I have Multipage in [jQuery Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile), and I work in the main page, and load data dynamically in the second page (`data-role=page`) into a `<ul data-role="listview">... </ul>`, and then this page is shown perfectly. Here in the second page, when I want to change to the main page and return and do the same, the list `<ul ...>` isn't refreshed. The first one works, but the second, when I return again, isn't refreshed.

The code is:

```
<div data-role="page" id="uno">

  <a href="#" onClick="LoadDataInto_MyUL_ListL();$.mobile.changePage('#dos');">

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="dos">
  <a href="#" onclick="$.mobile.changePage('#uno');" >Return</a>

  <ul data-role="listview" id="MyUL_List">
  </ul>

</div>
```

Inside `LoadDataInto_MyUL_ListL();`, I have `$('#MyUL_List').html("<li>...</li>")`, and firstly I had too `$('#MyUL_List').listview('refresh')`, but I had this error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

and I remove refresh, but without this error, listview doesn't refresh.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery mobile listview - check initialization is complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493215/jquery-mobile-listview-check-initialization-is-complete). I believe this answer will help you. Sometimes it can be tricky to know whether you should initialize a widget or refresh it, this answer will help with that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you need to initialize a jQuery Mobile widget before using it.

It can be initialized like this:

```
$('#MyUL_List').listview().listview('refresh');
```

The same thing stands for other jQuery Mobile elements.

Comment: It give me error below:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery1820979259907733649' of undefined

Comment: Then you are not calling it on a existing object. Are you sure your listview has an id -> MyUL_List

Comment: Yes, If I put alert($('#MyUL_List'))  , give me [Object]

Comment: @user1958457 Even if the `#MyUL_List` element does not exist, `$("#MyUL_List")` will return an object, it'll just return an object with no DOM element collection. A better check would be: `alert($("#MyUL_List").length)`, which will output `0` if nothing is found and `1` if something is found.